# Blurred circles and ellipses in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there any simple way to create a circle (or an ellipse) with blurred edges using matplotlib? This attempt got me as far as a normal circle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax=plt.axes()
plt.xlim(0,25)
plt.ylim(0,35)
circle = plt.Circle((10, 20), 1.0, color='royalblue')
plt.gca().add_patch(circle)
```

Is there a short step from this to a circle with blurred edges?
Cheers!

Comment: Which backend are you using? `import matplotlib; print matplotlib.get_backend()`, `TkAgg` for example has `antigrain (agg) rendering`.

Comment: Printing the backend gives: Qt4Agg.

Comment: Perhaps you could edit the question to add a screen shot of the problem. (Note, I am using TkAgg)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by 'blurred'. Do you mean antialiased? Transparent?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function that executed Circle several times, drawing concentric shapes of varying color and/or alpha.

Comment: I did that, but it does not seem optimal. I'd have to draw a lot of circles to obtain a nice gradient.